# GWT Dynamic Locale

Tags: gwt, localization, internationalization, locale

I want to set `gwt-locale` taking user chosen locale with the help of Spring `LocaleContextHolder`.

```
public static final String getCurrentLocale() {
    return LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage();
}
```

I actually have login interface in Spring MVC and inner Dashboard in `gwtp`. The same locale user chooses in outer interface before login has to be passed to `gwt` as well.

Unfortunately, I don't see any gwt inbuilt Locale setters.

**My `X.gwt.xml` with default locale as `kh` is :**

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder" />
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject" />
<inherits name="com.gwtplatform.mvp.Mvp" />
<inherits name="gwtquery.plugins.droppable.Droppable"/>

<source path="client" />
<source path="shared" />

<define-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector" is-multi-valued="false"/>
<set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector" value="com.prayagupd.client.mvp.XGInjector"/>
<set-configuration-property name="UiBinder.useSafeHtmlTemplates" value="true" /> 

<extend-property name="locale" values="kh" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
<set-property name="locale" value="kh"/>
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="kh"/>

<entry-point class="com.prayagupd.client.XEntryPoint"/>
```

**My `XEntryPoint.java` reads as :**

```
public class XEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    private final IUserServiceAsync rpc = GWT.create(IUserService.class);

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
            //
        rpc.getLocale(new AsyncCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String locale) {
                GWT.log("Locale From Spring : " + locale);
                GWT.log("Locale From GWT : " + LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName());
                            //here i want to set locale to gwt
                            //something like GWTLocale.setLocale(locale);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                GWT.log(caught.getMessage());
            }
        });
            DelayedBindRegistry.bind(ginjector);
            ginjector.getPlaceManager().revealCurrentPlace();
    }
}
```

**home.jsp for gwt-loading**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >

<%@tag import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spr" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<%@ attribute name="isgwt" required="true" type="java.lang.Boolean"%>


<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/reload.captcha.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/date.picker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/innerstyle.css" type="text/css" />

<c:if test="${not isgwt}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/mainstyler.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizer.custom.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${isgwt}">
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=${locale}">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="upd/upd.nocache.js"></script>
</c:if>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
</script>

<title><c:out value="${locale}"></c:out><spring:message code="page.header" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${empty username}">
                    <div class="header_con">
                        <div class="header_in">
                            <spr:header />
                            <spr:login />
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="main_con">
                            <jsp:doBody />
                            <spr:footer />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <div id="mainHolder">
                        <div id="wrapper">
                            <spr:headerInner />

                            <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1'
                                style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0"></iframe>
                            <div>

                                <div id="gwt_holder">
                                    <c:if test="${isgwt}">
                                        <div id="loader" class="loader">
                                        </div>
                                    </c:if>
                                    <div id="gwt"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</body>
</html>
```

Adding `?locale=en` or `?locale=kh` to gwt url works perfectly, but want to tell GWT only once that I want this locale programmatically and want it to work always with that locale onwards.

When I look at the `*.html` source code, I can see the injected the `<meta>` tag with proper `locale` passed from `SpringController`.

[image]

**References**

[GWT dynamic internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9074898/432903), Colin Alworth

[How i change the locale language of the application](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/TDt0uv9lzlE/bQ3cR3pVkCgJ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [*dynamic host page*](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dynamic_host_page.html) where you inject the proper `<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=XXX">`.

Remember the GWT [bootstrap sequence](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideBootstrap): once your `onModuleLoad` has been called, the choice of the permutation (which includes the locale) has already been made. You have to alter the bootstrap sequence so it chooses the *proper* permutation for the user. `?locale=XXX` does this (because the `locale` property has a [`<property-provider>`](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModuleXml) that reads the `locale` query-string parameter, among other things), as well as the `<meta>` above.

See also https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerSideLocaleSelection for some idea (BEWARE: deprecated project!)

Finally, there are a few issues with your `*.gwt.xml`, starting with `kh` not being a [valid locale](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47).

The workflow for internationalizing your app is as follows:

1. list your locales:

   ```
   <extend-property name="locale" value="en" />
   <extend-property name="locale" value="fr" />
   ```
2. remove the `default` locale by setting the `locale` property to the full list of supported locales:

   ```
   <set-property name="locale" value="en,fr" />
   ```
3. set the fallback locale:

   ```
   <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en" />
   ```

Optionally, you can select how the locale is determined using the properties `locale.queryparam`, `locale.cookie`, `locale.usemeta`, `locale.useragent`, and `locale.searchorder` (see the `I18N.gwt.xml` for their default and accepted values).

And finally, add code to select the locale (e.g. the dynamic `<meta>` above)

Comment: I have added `<c:if test="${isgwt}">
 <meta name="gwt:property" value="locale=${locale}">
</c:if>` to `home.jsp` as well.(updated `home.jsp` above) Am passing "locale" paramater from `SpringController`. But `LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName()` is always returning  `kh` even if am passing `locale=en` from `SpringController`. **Anything missing or misplaced??**

Comment: You should have `<set-property name="locale" value="kh"/>`, either remove the line or set `value` to `kh,en`; but then `?locale=en` shouldn't have worked. Are you sure the `${locale}` from Spring is correct?

Comment: I tried removing `<set-property name="locale" value="kh"/>` to `<extend-property name="locale" values="kh" />
    <extend-property name="locale" values="en" /> <set-property name="locale" value="kh, en"/>`. True `?locale=kh` doesn't work. I have updated screenshot above to prove the correct `locale` being passed from `SpringController`. [html-source-with-meta](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wKlLD.png) GWT is warning me `com.google.gwt.core.ext.BadPropertyValueException: Property 'locale' cannot be set to unexpected value 'default'`

Comment: Actually `<meta name="gwt:property" value="locale=${locale}">` is not working.

Comment: 2 things: add `<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="kh"/>` to declare the _default_ locale; the attribute name for the `<meta>` should be `content`, not `value` (my bad, I mistyped it initially in my answer)

Comment: Updated the answer with more details, taken from the comments above.

Comment: It worked for me with a little change: <extend-property name="locale" values="en,fr" /> (notice the "values" attribute)

Answer (score 2):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16295300/432903) inspired by [Thomas Broyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer),

**X.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.3.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.3.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="x">
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.json.JSON"/>

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject" />
    <inherits name="com.gwtplatform.mvp.Mvp" />
    <inherits name="gwtquery.plugins.droppable.Droppable"/>

    <source path="client" />
    <source path="shared" />

    <define-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector" is-multi-valued="false"/>
    <set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector" value="com.prayagupd.client.mvp.XGInjector"/>
    <set-configuration-property name="UiBinder.useSafeHtmlTemplates" value="true" /> 

    <extend-property name="locale" values="kh" />
    <extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
    <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="kh"/>

    <entry-point class="com.prayagupd.client.XEntryPoint"/>

</module>
```

And , `home.jsp`

```
<c:if test="${isgwt}">
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=${locale}">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="upd/upd.nocache.js"></script>
</c:if>
```

locale being passed from Spring Controller

```
{
    //...
    modelMap.put("locale", locale);
    return "home";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Broyer's answer is correct, except one thing. You don't mandatory need to use "dynamic host page", meta tag can be defined dynamically on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax("rest/service/default-locale").done(function(data) {
        if (data) {           
            var metaLocale = $("<meta name='gwt:property' content='locale=" + data + "'>");
            $("head").append(metaLocale);
        }
        var jsLink = $("<script src='myapp.nocache.js'>");
        $("head").append(jsLink);
    });
</script>
```

This way any additional modifications can be done on the client side before GWT app starts.