# How do I convert a String to Double in GWT using a specific locale?

Tags: java, gwt

In java this is easy to do:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
myNumber = nf.parse(myString);
```

However, I can't seem to do the same thing in GWT. First I incorporated the locale in MyModule.gwt.xml

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="sl_SI"/>
```

There also exists the NumberFormat class: com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat;
which uses the "default" locale. Default here means a fixed locale that is very similar to "en_US" and not default chosen by the browser or application.

It seems there is no way to set the NumberFormat to accept a different locale. Quite frankly, I dont see any point then.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want to parse according to a specific locale? or to the locale of your application? (which **can** be different from `default`)

Comment: @Thomas: actually I would like to do both

Comment: @Christian: nice it worked. Please re-post it as an answer.

Comment: Parsing according to _any_ specific locale is not currently possible in GWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `<meta name='gwt:property' content='locale=sl_SI' />` to the html host page

Here's an explanation on why it works like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16295300/572830

Here's the broader and detailed explanation: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not. Locale specific code on the client is very limited in GWT. You can try to use native JavaScript (with all the drawbacks).

But I found that it's easier to just call a server method in such cases. For one, I usually don't have to convert many values and the rate I need this method is low, so the overkill of send bytes over the network is bearable in this case.

If this isn't an option for you and you only need to be able to *parse* such a number, I suggest to take the format for the locale apart. This is easier than it looks if you follow this approach:

- Figure out what the decimal point (comma or point) is.
- Create a negative pattern which matches anything that isn't the decimal point or digits, i.e.: `'[^0-9' + decimalPoint + ']'`
- Use this pattern to remove anything that matches from the string
- Replace decimal point with `.`

This allows parsing. For formatting, I don't have a good solution.

Comment: I am very happy to say that Christian's solution `<meta name='gwt:property' content='locale=sl_SI' />` did work. While doing the parsing on your own is easy if the locale is known, its a bit tedious to get the valid standard to do it right if its foreign...

Comment: His solution works if you have only one locale. What do you do when you need to format according to a locale saved with an object in a database?

Comment: As explained by the link he provided: Tip: The preferred time to explicitly set locale is to do so before your GWT module is invoked. You can change the locale from within your GWT module by adding or changing the locale query string in the current URL and reloading the page. Keep in mind that after reloading the page, your module will restart.

Comment: You're missing the most important point: I have several locales on a single page (for example, in an app that allows people to translate between languages). So one global, fixed locale will not do.

Comment: Ah I see. That indeed is a problem. Luckly however, not one I currently have. Only one locale for one page for me.