# How to Set the Ui element names in gwt application based on currency?

Tags: gwt, internationalization

We are trying to extend our application through out the world.So we have some labels, buttons etc have 
to be changed based on the currency. We have currency at browser side and i need to change the label names
based on that currency by using properties files.
Can any body have suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks & Regards,
Msnaidu

Comment: If the currency notations go along with a country/language, you can just use the internationalization dynamic binding  https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n

Comment: Thanks for your reply Deanna, I was already went through the above documentation.It requires the locale pass along with the url, but i was not happy about passed the locale as a parameter for every country.

Comment: User may not have idea about the url and locale, so by default we have to do something from our side, we can not let it to the user.

Comment: If you use a JSP page instead of html, after you validate the user you embed the local in the page.

Comment: I can get locale from the browser, but i don't know how to use it at my client side, can you please clarify me?

Comment: Can you explain better the part: "We have currency at browser side" ?

Comment: The user can select his own currency from list box, based on his selection i have to change strings, labels etc...

Comment: This post may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293796/gwt-dynamic-locale .  The basic idea is using a jsp page to determine the local then setting the meta data for the generated html page.  Then the gwt code will use that value for dynamic binding.  In the JSP you can use whatever you want to decide the locale, either browser settings or a user defined setting in a database.