# GWT: Inject Meta Tag Runtime

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to implement GWT internationalization, but the locale property is based on user configuration.

I have tried injecting the following tag on index file in order to set the locale property:

***meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=es"***

But, How can i set up the property properly on Runtime?

Comment: How you're "injecting" this meta tag? Is it after or before GWT module load?

Comment: Hi. After GWT module load.

Answer (score 1):

A third option is to dynamically read the user locale in your html file meta tag, so *before* loading GWT:

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=<%=request.getLocale()%>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't translate your application at runtime, not without reloading the application, because you need to download another permutation.

So that leaves you with just the two standard options

#### Meta tag

Present the website with the meta tag as you already know

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=es">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Load the GWT compiled module code                           -->
    <script src="com.google.gwt.examples.i18n.ColorNameLookupExample.nocache.js " />
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Query string

You just need to load the application using `locale`

```
http://www.example.org/myapp.html?locale=es
```

### Here is a [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067308/1018903) on how to choose a locale and reload the application.

There is *limited* support, that affected only currency data, number format, and date/time formats. See more about [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#RuntimeLocales)

Comment: Absolutely: "inject" your meta tag on the server, using JSP or whichever templating you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jsp file as a welcome page. Then you can embed your html contents into this file. In the way you can configure the following line too.

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=<%=request.getLocale()%>">
```